# TypeError: Object(…) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux

I am attempting to peform Auth with Firebase and Redux. When I try to Login I am getting an error: " Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function"

Here is my 'Login' Component:

```
import React, {  Component }  from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { signIn } from '../store/actions/authActions'

class Login extends Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state={
    email:'',
    password:''
  };

  this.onChangeEmail=this.onChangeEmail.bind(this);
  this.onChangePassword =this.onChangePassword.bind(this);
  this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
}

onChangeEmail(e) {
  this.setState({
    email:e.target.value
  });
}

onChangePassword(e){
  this.setState({
    password:e.target.value
  });
}
  onSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.signIn(this.state);
  }


render() {
    return(
        <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-9 col-md-7 col-lg-5 mx-auto">
            <div className="card card-signin my-5">
              <div className="card-body">
                <h5 className="card-title text-center">Sign In</h5>
                <form className="form-signin" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                  <div className="form-label-group">
                  <label>Email address
                    <input type="email" id="inputEmail" className="form-control" placeholder="Email address" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.onChangeEmail} required autoFocus />
                    </label>
                  </div>

                  <div className="form-label-group">
                  <label>Password
                    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" 
                    value={this.state.password}
                    onChange={this.onChangePassword}
                    required />
                  </label>                   
                  </div>

                  <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
                    <input type="checkbox" className="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" />
                    <label className="custom-control-label" >Remember password
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block text-uppercase" type="submit">Sign in</button>
                  <hr className="my-4" />

                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
 }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
   signIn: (creds) => dispatch(signIn(creds))
  }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps) (Login);
```

Here is my action creator --> authAction.js

```
export const signIn = (credentials) => {
return (dispatch, getState, {getFirebase}) => {
    const firebase = getFirebase();
    firebase.auth().signInWIthEmailandPassword(
        credentials.email,
        credentials.password
    ).then(()=> {
        dispatch ({ type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS'})
    }).catch((err) => {
        dispatch('LOGIN_ERROR', err)
    })
 }
}
```

Here is my reducer --> authReducer.js

```
const initialState = {
authError: null
}

 const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

switch (action.type){
    case 'LOGIN_ERROR': 
        console.log('Login Success')
        return  {
            ...state, 
            authError: 'Login Failed'
        }
    case 'LOGIN_SUCCESS':
        console.log('Login Success');
        return {
            ...state,
            authError: null
        }
        default:
            return state;
 }
}

export default authReducer;
```

The dispatch is mapping to the component because I can see it when I console.log(this.props) in the Login Component. But I dont what I am missing. I am using 'redux-thunk' as middleware. Maybe that is an issue?

Here is my 'index.js' file where I configure my middleware:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Root from './components/Root'
import './style.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { reactReduxFirebase, getFirebase } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import rootReducer from './store/reducers/rootReducer';

import configFB from './config/configFB'


import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';


const store = createStore(rootReducer, 
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument(getFirebase)),
    reactReduxFirebase(configFB), // redux binding for firebase
  )
); 

ReactDOM.render(<Root store={store} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I have a sandbox with the code located [here!](https://codesandbox.io/s/p9v25xm3l7?fontsize=14)

Comment: ```
return (dispatch, getState, getFirebase) => {
  const firebase = getFirebase();
  ...
}
```

you don't need bracket at getFirebase

Comment: When I remove the brackets, the error comes back as "getFirebase is not a function."

Comment: Perhaps share a codesandbox.

Comment: Sandbox doesn't has your code ?

Comment: Sorry, fixed --> https://codesandbox.io/s/p9v25xm3l7?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0):

There is now a way to import ` { withFirebase } from  ‘react-redux-firebase’  this then allows you to turn a component into a higher order component.

```
import React, {  Component } from 'react';
import { withFirebase } from 'react-redux-firebase'

class Login extends Component {
   state={
   email:‘’,
   password:‘’
   };

 onChangeEmail = (e) => {
   this.setState({
   email:e.target.value
  });
  }

onChangePassword = (e) => {
   this.setState({
  password:e.target.value
  });
}

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.firebase.login(this.state).catch(err => 
   console.log(err.message))
   }

   return(
    Component Markup
    )

 export default withFirebase(Login);
```

When you wrap the component in the withFirebase() function, it turns the Component into a Higher Order Component and makes certain firebase functions available to the component as props. hence the `this.props.firebase.login()` in the onSubmit() function. I didn't need an action for the login.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this error when trying to use hooks in an older version of react. The solution was to upgrade the react version. That likely applies to attempts to import other non-existent properties of a package as well.